# How to get ArrayList from another activity to Another

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an arraylist in my RetrieveActivity.java and i would like to transfer it to another activity which is GraphActivity.java. I need that arraylist data to make graph in my GraphActivity.

here is my RetrieveActivity.java code

```
public class RetrieveActivity extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrieve);
    }
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{   



    public ArrayList<String> tempList=new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> dataList=new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> atList=new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> timeList=new ArrayList<String>();
}
}
```

so I would like to get the arraylist data to the GraphActivity.

```
public class GraphActivity extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph);    
    }


}
```

tq in advance.

Comment: Will you start GraphActivity from RetrieveActivity? If so, this tutorial illustrates how to add extra data to an Intent when starting an Activity: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: @jpdelacroix yes i will start it in retrieveActivity by button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your RetrieveActivity class, do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RetrieveActivity.this, GraphActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list1", mArrayList1);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list2", mArrayList2);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list3", mArrayList3);
startActivity(intent);
```

And then in your GraphActivity, do this to retrieve the list:

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
ArrayList<String> newList1 = i.getStringArrayListExtra("list1");
ArrayList<String> newList2 = i.getStringArrayListExtra("list2");
ArrayList<String> newList3 = i.getStringArrayListExtra("list3");
```

Comment: HI there, tq for your helpful info, may i know the intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list", dataList); is it correct in this form ? how about if 2 array list going to be transfer... does it means i jsut pput another intent.putStringArrayListExtra("alist", atList); ?

Comment: Yes, just pass another list in usinf ntent.putStringArrayListExtra("list1", mArrayList1); again, I updated the answer to show you

Comment: hi there, may i know i should be putting that intent in the asynctask class or retrieve activity class?

Comment: You should put it in the onPostExecute method on your AsyncTask class. This way, when the task finishes, it will put the arraylist(s) into the intent and start the new activity

Comment: hi , erm i put the intent on the RetriveActivity there but it doesn't see the dataList since it was private Asyntask. May i know how can i deliver that Arraylist to the RetrieveActivity Class

Comment: hi, i understand if i put on the onPostExecute, it will start another activity as long as the asyntask finish runnning . But what i have on the onPostExecute is a bunch of data table. I wanna give another option display which is graph when being press/slide gesture. for the moment i would like a button to trigger the graph instead

Comment: In regards to it being private to the AsyncTask, make the lists global and then update them in the AsyncTask instead of declaring them. Then, you can use the updated values in RetrieveActivity.as for the onPostExecute, I'm not really understanding what you are trying to do, sorry ^.^

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare the ArrayLists as

```
public static ArrayList<String> tempList=new ArrayList<String>();
```

In you  GraphActivity you can use

ArrayList newList1 = RetrieveActivity.tempList;`

Answer (score 0):

late answer, but good
Declare an object that implements Parcelable, implement all methods.
Watch and be careful when you write read and write methods, all variables must be in the same way.
Then fill this object with data, and add this object to ArrayList that is of type object this object that you create previously.

then create intent and Bundle, and put this Arraylist in it

```
          Intent intentTest = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Calculation.class);
            data.putParcelableArrayList("test",  Razlike);
            intentTest.putExtra("dataS", data);
            //Log.i("intentCheck",String.valueOf(intentTest.getParcelableArrayListExtra("test").size()));
            startActivity(intentTest);
```

in other activity read that, and that is all

happy coding